# JOIN is MUCH slower than a UNION, even with indexes

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a query:

```
SELECT study."id"
FROM study
JOIN report ON (report."studyId" = study."id")
WHERE 
study.facts->'patientName'->>'value' = 'HELLO WORLD' OR 
report.variables->'patientName'->>'value' = 'HELLO WORLD'
```

All tables have indexes.

Why is this query taking 4.5s across 6000 rows? Explain analyze output below:

```
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| QUERY PLAN                                                                                                                                                                                 |
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| Hash Join  (cost=383.69..1403.67 rows=39 width=52) (actual time=2734.257..2734.260 rows=0 loops=1)                                                                                         |
|   Hash Cond: ((study.id)::text = (report."studyId")::text)                                                                                                                                 |
|   Join Filter: ((((study.facts -> 'patientName'::text) ->> 'value'::text) = 'HELLO WORLD'::text) OR (((report.variables -> 'patientName'::text) ->> 'value'::text) = 'HELLO WORLD'::text)) |
|   Rows Removed by Join Filter: 7453                                                                                                                                                        |
|   ->  Seq Scan on study  (cost=0.00..1000.23 rows=7523 width=70) (actual time=0.020..13.548 rows=7523 loops=1)                                                                             |
|   ->  Hash  (cost=290.53..290.53 rows=7453 width=70) (actual time=5.052..5.053 rows=7453 loops=1)                                                                                          |
|         Buckets: 8192  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 808kB                                                                                                                                     |
|         ->  Seq Scan on report  (cost=0.00..290.53 rows=7453 width=70) (actual time=0.014..3.235 rows=7453 loops=1)                                                                        |
| Planning Time: 0.896 ms                                                                                                                                                                    |
| Execution Time: 2734.323 ms                                                                                                                                                                |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I have a UNION query that does the same thing, but is much quicker (0.001s). I want to know more about why my JOIN query is so much slower:

```
SELECT id::text
FROM study
WHERE study.facts->'patientName'->>'value' = 'HELLO WORLD'
UNION
SELECT report."studyId"::text
FROM report
WHERE report.variables->'patientName'->>'value' = 'HELLO WORLD';
```

```
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| QUERY PLAN                                                                                                                                      |
|-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| HashAggregate  (cost=143.12..143.51 rows=39 width=32) (actual time=0.040..0.041 rows=0 loops=1)                                                 |
|   Group Key: ((study.id)::text)                                                                                                                 |
|   ->  Append  (cost=4.58..143.02 rows=39 width=32) (actual time=0.038..0.039 rows=0 loops=1)                                                    |
|         ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on study  (cost=4.58..134.14 rows=38 width=32) (actual time=0.026..0.026 rows=0 loops=1)                           |
|               Recheck Cond: (((facts -> 'patientName'::text) ->> 'value'::text) = 'HELLO WORLD'::text)                                          |
|               ->  Bitmap Index Scan on "IDX_facts_patientName"  (cost=0.00..4.57 rows=38 width=0) (actual time=0.023..0.023 rows=0 loops=1)     |
|                     Index Cond: (((facts -> 'patientName'::text) ->> 'value'::text) = 'HELLO WORLD'::text)                                      |
|         ->  Index Scan using "IDX_variables_patientName" on report  (cost=0.28..8.30 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=0.012..0.012 rows=0 loops=1) |
|               Index Cond: (((variables -> 'patientName'::text) ->> 'value'::text) = 'HELLO WORLD'::text)                                        |
| Planning Time: 0.560 ms                                                                                                                         |
| Execution Time: 0.103 ms                                                                                                                        |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Updated with the query plan for union. Yes, I have indexes on the conditions in the WHERE clause. They are JSONB columns, but they have indexes on them. Doing them separately (i.e. not joining) is much faster

Comment: Lemme try something locally. I remember Postgres being smarter than this about ORs, though still fallible in more complex cases. Which version of Postgres are you using?

Comment: Okay. I'm really perplexed, as this table is so simple. Running version 11.x

Comment: Hmm, I set up a simple schema except without jsonb at https://pastebin.com/2SnN6CGX and am seeing similar behavior. Guess OR really does kill it like @a_horse_with_no_name suggested. It's trying to join with that OR clause as part of the predicate instead of just filtering the results after.

Comment: Should it though? Is there another way of writing this as a JOIN? I feel like doing an OR across a joined column is super common.

Comment: Hard for me to tell without a populated DB to play with. My test schema isn't realistic. I tried using a subquery to force it to filter after the join, and it refused.

`EXPLAIN ANALYZE
SELECT sq.id
FROM (
  SELECT s.id, s.facts, r.variables
  FROM test.study s JOIN test.report r ON s.id = r.id
) sq
WHERE sq.facts = 'abc' OR sq.variables = 'def';`

And `set enable_hashjoin = false` forced it to filter after joining. It's worth you trying just to see if it _can_ plan that way, but you probably don't want to rely on that.

Comment: Are you asking why the first query is slow or are you asking why the 2 queries take different times? Assuming the first query is fully indexed then the performance is limited by the environment it is running on. The 2 queries take different execution times because they are different queries returning different results - so not sure why you think they would run in a similar time?

Comment: I would attempt `WHERE ... OR EXISTS (...)` since you don't actually need the report table.

Comment: D'oh, my insert queries were failing, so my DB actually had 0 rows. After inserting 4096 into each table, I'm seeing the expected join-then-filter behavior with an OR. Sorry for the mess.

I just noticed the `Hash Cond: ((study.id)::text = (report."studyId")::text)`. Do you have indexes on those ID cols? If not, this query plan makes sense to me.

Comment: Yes, I have indexes on those columns

Comment: Is that repeatable?  It looks baffling to me that the hash join takes so long compared to the seq scans.  (OR can be challenging but they are not magically bad and the OR alone cannot explain the slowness of the hash join operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`OR` is always difficult for the optimiser(s). Since you dont need any fields from the `report` table, you could tuck that away into an EXISTS() subquery, this will probably result in a bitmap-index scan.:

---

```
SELECT s."id"
FROM study s
WHERE s.facts->'patientName'->>'value' = 'HELLO WORLD'
OR  EXISTS (
        SELECT * FROM report r
        WHERE r."studyId" = s."id"
        AND r.variables->'patientName'->>'value' = 'HELLO WORLD'
        );
```

Comment: Thanks! This is certainly much faster (down to 500ms, from ~4s)

Comment: And: does it result in a bitmap index scan?

Comment: No. It seems to result in a Seq scan for the study.

Comment: This doesn't do exactly the same thing as the first query in the question. The first query only returns studies whose IDs match a report ID. But... X-Y problem.

Comment: @sudo : you might be right. Maybe there was an accidentical logical flaw in the OP's implementation, too?

Comment: Perhaps i stuffed up copying my example code. All I want is: Give me all study ids where either the report.variables.patientName for the study matches, or the study.facts.patientName matches. There is always 1 report for each study.

Comment: In that case (1-1 matching) you could not suffer from the hole that @sudo detected.

Comment: Yep, this answer does what you want. I'm still wondering about the original query, but it's a moot point now.

Answer (score 2):

JOINS and UNIONS are two completely different operations.

- **JOIN** adds columns from both tables to the result set, matching both tables with you matching criteria ( `WHERE CLAUSE` )
- **UNION** on the others hand, append the result of 1 table on top of the other. In more detail, the difference between an `UNION` and a `UNION ALL`, is that the union is a `SELECT DISTINCT` from the `UNION ALL`

In summary, the `UNION` does not require a matching criteria to select the `ROWS` to add to the result.

Comment: Okay. That makes sense. So perhaps I am misusing JOIN here. I do not need the results of the report table. I just need the id of the study

Comment: Still, I would expect the join to be not much slower than the union here.